# Sum of subgradients belongs to subgradient of sums?

Tags: calculus, continuity, convex-optimization, subgradient

I was going through this page : https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~lienart/blog_opti_basics.html , and at the end of part 1 "Subgradient and First-order Optimality Condition", the author says:

> Before moving on, it is useful to note (and not too hard to convince oneself) that the following inclusion holds for the subdifferential of a sum:
>   $\sum_i ∂f_i⊆∂∑_if_i$.

Can anyone explain what this means? If $f_i$ is not differentiable, then it can have multiple values of subgradient, right? Then what does the sum of subgradients of the functions $f_i$ amount to? And how do we show the above result?

Comment: Sum of subdifferential is just the direct sum of the sets. Proof is quite straightforward, take any element from the set on the LHS and show that it exists even in RHS. Just requires you to use the definition of subdifferential.

Comment: @TenaliRaman Yep, I was thinking about Union instead of sum. Sorry for the stupid question! And thanks for your response!

Comment: The sum of the sets is the set of the sums.

Answer (score 12):

Suppose $\xi_k \in \partial f_k(x)$, then
$f_k(z) \ge f_k(x) + \langle \xi_k, z-x \rangle$ for all $z$.

Hence
$\sum_k f_k(z) \ge \sum_k f_k(z) + \langle \sum_k \xi_k, z-x \rangle$ for all $z$ and so we have
$\sum_k \xi_k \in \partial \sum_k f_k(x)$.

Note that for convex functions in a practical context, it is typically the case that we have
equality and lack of equality is pathological in some sense.

For example, a sufficient condition (Rockafellar) is
$\cap_k \operatorname{ri} ( \operatorname{dom} f_k ) \neq \emptyset$.

As an aside, the notion of subdifferential can be extended to locally Lipschitz functions (subgradient) where the containment goes in the
opposite direction (ignoring pathologies), that is the subgradients satisfy
$\partial \sum_k f_k(x) \subset \sum_k \partial f_k(x)$. An easy
example if $f_1(x)= \max(0,x)$, $f_2(x) = -f_1(-x)$ in which case we have $f_1(x)+f_2(x) = x$ and so
$\partial \sum_k f_k(0)= \{1\}$, $\sum_k \partial f_k(0) = [0,2]$.
Of course, $f_2$ is not convex, so there is no contradiction here.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the inclusion $\partial \sum_k f_k(x) \subset \sum_k \partial f_k(x)$ of locally Lipschitz function?

Comment: @Analyst For example, Proposition 2.3.3 "Optimization and nonsmooth analysis", Frank Clarke.

Comment: Thank you so much for your indication! I got it.