# Breaking up subgradients into pieces

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, subgradient

I was giving [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188858/sum-of-subgradients-belongs-to-subgradient-of-sums) some thought and could not help but wonder the following.  Suppose that $A_1,\dots,A_k$ are pairwise disjoint open sets and $g_1,\dots,g_k$ are smooth functions, then $1_{A_j}g_j$ (where $1_{A_j}$ is the indicator function on $A_j$) is sub-differentiable  but is is true that any subgradient $G$ of $\sum_{j=1}^k I_{A_j} g_j$ can be written as
$$
G = \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j} \nabla g_j?
$$
*(since $g_j$ is continuously differentiable)*

Comment: Are you assuming that $1_{A_j}g_j$ is convex?

Comment: No, just general non-convex functions.  However, $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint... if it helps..

Comment: $1_{A_j}g_j$ is not necessarily subdifferentiable.

Comment: I think if $A_i$ are intervals then this sould be okay?